# How to change font size in button by code?

Tags: c#

```
private void arrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if (turn == 0)
    {
        button.Text = "X";
        button.Enabled = false;
        turn = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Text = "O";
        button.Enabled = false;
        turn = 0;
    }
}
```

I have an array button, When I resize the buttons by code: larger or smaller. I want to resize font X, O. How do it by code?

Answer (score 18):

The Fontsize can be set as follows :

```
int newSize = 10;
button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, newSize);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think u r looking for something like:

```
button.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(32);
 // OR
button.Font.Size = FontUnit.Larger;
```

Comment: Error : The name "FontUnit" does not exist in the current context

Comment: Is it a web application or windows application ? The one i suggested is web application and uses the " System.Web.UI.WebControls" namespace